# How to display the following matrix in texmaker?

Tags: matrices, texmaker

[image]

I want to display the following matrix in texmaker. please suggest.

Comment: Welcome o TeX.sx. It has nothing to do with TeXmaker. It is just an editor. Have you read an introduction to LaTeX? It is all about Math mode.

Comment: yes, I am able to write the matrix part but unable to write that Es. PM = \begin{pmatrix}
        \alpha_{11} & \alpha_{12} & ... & \alpha_{1M} \\
        \alpha_{21} & \alpha_{22} & ... & \alpha_{2M} \\
        .           & .           &.    &.          \\
        .           & .           &.    &.          \\
       .           & .           &.    &.          \\
       \alpha_{M1} & \alpha_{M2} & ... & \alpha_{MM}
         \end{pmatrix}

Comment: I am unable o write the left side Es and the upper side Es. Please suggest.

Comment: Use `blkarray`: `\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}

\[PM=
\begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
      & E_1 & E_2 & \cdots & E_M\\
    \begin{block}{c(cccc)}
    E_1 & \alpha_{11} & \alpha_{12} & \cdots & \alpha_{1M}\\ 
    E_2 & \alpha_{21} &\alpha_{22} & \cdots & \alpha_{2M}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    E_M & \alpha_{M1} & \alpha_{M2} & \cdots & \alpha_{MM}\\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document} `

Comment: It worked. Thanks Schrödinger's cat.

Comment: This has been asked many times: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=bordermatrix

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
$PM = 
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
& E_1 & E_2 & \Cdots & E_M \\
E_1 & \alpha_{11} & \alpha_{12} & \Cdots & \alpha_{1M} \\
E_2 & \alpha_{12} & \alpha_{22} & \Cdots & \alpha_{2M} \\
\Vdots & \Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots \\
E_M & \alpha_{M_1} & \alpha_{M2} & \Cdots & \alpha_{MM}
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image]